# How can I debug Unicorn that crashes with "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" as if the body returned from the app would be nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, stack-trace, unicorn

I'm running a Rails 3.2.13 app at Heroku with Unicorn, and I get seemingly randomly and very often (e.g. few times a minute) an unicorn error in my logs that tells the following, but not much else:

```
Jul 08 17:12:41 my_app app/web.1:  E, [2013-07-08T14:12:41.153875 #21] ERROR -- : app error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) 
Jul 08 17:12:41 my_app app/web.1:  E, [2013-07-08T14:12:41.157119 #21] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_response.rb:60:in `http_response_write' 
Jul 08 17:12:41 my_app app/web.1:  E, [2013-07-08T14:12:41.157292 #21] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:562:in `process_client' 
Jul 08 17:12:41 my_app app/web.1:  E, [2013-07-08T14:12:41.157367 #21] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:632:in `worker_loop' 
Jul 08 17:12:41 my_app app/web.1:  E, [2013-07-08T14:12:41.157443 #21] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.2.96/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/unicorn_instrumentation.rb:22:in `call' 
Jul 08 17:12:41 my_app app/web.1:  E, [2013-07-08T14:12:41.157523 #21] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.2.96/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/unicorn_instrumentation.rb:22:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>' 
Jul 08 17:12:41 my_app app/web.1:  E, [2013-07-08T14:12:41.157600 #21] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers' 
Jul 08 17:12:41 my_app app/web.1:  E, [2013-07-08T14:12:41.157724 #21] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start' 
Jul 08 17:12:41 my_app app/web.1:  E, [2013-07-08T14:12:41.157802 #21] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>' 
Jul 08 17:12:41 my_app app/web.1:  E, [2013-07-08T14:12:41.157870 #21] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load' 
Jul 08 17:12:41 my_app app/web.1:  E, [2013-07-08T14:12:41.158027 #21] ERROR -- : /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

Investigating the Unicorn source a bit it seems that the body in the response that the app returns is nil, and that causes the crash. But I do not get any output from the app about this, and this seems to happen even when no requests are logged at all. I tried adding debug  prints to rack middle ware but those do not get printed at all.

I'm not very experienced with Unicorn and Rack so I'm asking for tips how to debug this further.

While looking for similar questions online I found: http://jeffrafter.tumblr.com/post/8459308338/recalcitrant-unicorns which seems exactly similar situation. I tried the telnet approach with `heroku run` but it seems to say "Connection refused" at the port which is shown in the logs to be used by Unicorn. Are there other ways to get the real stack trace?

Comment: if you run the server in development with unicorn does it work? I doubt this is a heroku specific error.

Comment: Good point. But I haven't been able to reproduce this error outside heroku. I'm guessing at the moment that these seemingly randomly happening events could be caused by bots accessing the site and expecially robots.txt (which google webmaster tools reported it couldn't access). Anyway the original question remains, as if there would be ways to get some output from what's happening internally it could help to figure this out.

Comment: One step closer.. I found out that making a simple curl request to an asset file, e.g. robots.txt causes this error (and internal server error reply to curl) but requesting that with a browser works fine.

Comment: well unicorn workers will be killed by their masters if beyond a configured threshold. This may just be a heroku edge case. In my experience heroku and unicorn is too hard because you have no access to the system... tuning it is hard. Plus its forking nature doesn't work well in this environment. I usually default to puma on heroku. http://ylan.segal-family.com/blog/2012/08/20/better-performance-on-heroku-thins-vs-unicorn-vs-puma/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like NewRelic code in your stack trace.  You might try turning off NewRelic to see if that resolves the error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I got the problem now avoided, by serving the assets that caused this by different ways. But if I get back to looking at the root of this, I could try if the new relic is the problem. (although I think I tried that also locally without new relic on, but not sure..)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well.  Turned out to be memcached store was full.  Try flushing your Rails cache.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your case. Hopefully it helps other's googling their way here. In my case the issue seemed to happen when serving robots.txt. I didn't find the root cause, but changing robots.txt to come from rack middleware solved the issue for me.